# Hamiltonian of the BEC in 2nd quantization

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian, second-quantization, bose-einstein-condensate

If I have $N$ non-interacting particle (bosons) forming a BEC that is trapped to
$x = 0 $ (assume the system to be 1D) by an applied harmonic potential $V=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^{2}x^{2}$

How can I write the Hamiltonian of the BEC in 2nd quantization; what is the
corresponding **energy spectrum** and mostly, what about **stationary states**?

(I expect it to be something of the form of $N$ harmonic oscillators but i have no clue how to formalize it and obtain it, especially stationary states, thanks in advance)

Comment: Do you know second quantization? What is exactly the problem that you encounter with the usual prescription?

Comment: Welcome to PhysicsSE. You could try to write the Hamiltonian of a single harmonic oscillator, as the particles do not interact it should be easy to extend to $N$ oscillators.

Comment: the problem is that i know how single operator (e.g. kinetic one) act and can be written in 2nd quant, but as soon as i have the potential idk which basis should i use in order for the Hamiltonian to be diagonal, the standard wavefunctions of harmonic oscillator?